# IndexError: list index out of range on APP STARTUP v 3.16.1, 3.16.0.2, 3.14.0

Tags: qgis

During start up of the app, the following error occurs.

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
IndexError: list index out of range 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "n:/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 112, in loadAlgorithms
    folder = ScriptUtils.resetScriptFolder(folder)
  File "n:/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 114, in resetScriptFolder
    commonSettingPath = os.path.join(paths[appIndex], paths[profileIndex])
IndexError: list index out of range

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.1-Hannover Hannover, b381a90dca 

Python Path:
n:/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python
r:/Users/timv/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
r:/Users/timv/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
n:/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\Scripts
N:\QGIS 3.16\bin\python37.zip
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\DLLs
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib
N:\QGIS 3.16\bin
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
n:\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
r:/Users/timv/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

What is the cause and/or remedy for the above?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you added python scripts that don't follow the form of a script in the processing toolboox. These scripts are run when you start the application and if the form is not correct it gives you this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem, renaming the Profile folder -> default  (C:\Users[Your_User_Windows_Nmae]\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default) with the name default_old.

When you start again Qgis, the folder is created again, and the problem desapears.

You must reinstall your plugins (and perhpas you discover that a plugin is not working well).